# Return an object from a popup window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window which pop-ups another Window. I want the second Window to be able to return an object to the first Window when a button is pressed. How would I do this?

Comment: Is the new window modal to the first window?

Comment: At first I didn't even know what a modal window was but I figured it out.  Thomas' code below with a slight edit worked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can expose a property on the second window, so that the first window can retrieve it.

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
    ...

    private void btnPromptFoo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var w = new Window2();
        if (w.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            string foo = w.Foo;
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class Window2 : Window
{
    ...

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return txtFoo.Text; }
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the user interacts with the window and presses a button before I want the parent window to get the value.

Comment: I figured it out.  The problem was it should be if(w.ShowDialog() == false).

Comment: @Reflux: are you sure ? ShowDialog returns false when the user cancels the dialog, so you probably don't want to take the value into account in that case

Comment: Probably because the button the user presses in my case also closes the window.

Comment: You should set the DialogResult explicitly then

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to expose a property, and you want to make the usage a little more explicit, you can overload `ShowDialog`:

```
public DialogResult ShowDialog(out MyObject result)
{
   DialogResult dr = ShowDialog();
   result = (dr == DialogResult.Cancel) 
      ? null 
      : MyObjectInstance;
   return dr;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 6):

Holy mother of Mars, this took me forever to figure out:

WINDOW 1:

```
if ((bool)window.ShowDialog() == true)
{
   Window2 content = window.Content as Window2;
   string result = content.result;
   int i = 0;
}
```

WINDOW 2:

```
public partial class Window2 : UserControl
{
    public string result
    {
        get { return resultTextBox.Text; }
    }

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window.GetWindow(this).DialogResult = true;
        Window.GetWindow(this).Close();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button IsDefault="True" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that.

In parent window make a corresponding ClosingEvent like this :

```
private void NewWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        NewWindow nw = (NewWindow)sender;

        object Receiver = nw.Sender;
    }
```

...and in the child window change your code implement the "sender" like this :

```
    public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    public object Sender { get; set; }

    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Sender = objectYouWantToSend;
    }
}
```

So when you put data into the object "Sender" in child window, while closing this window will put the data into the "Receiver" variable.

I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call any method of the popup window like this:

```
int value = 0;
if ((bool)poupWindow.ShowDialog() == true) {
  value = poupWindow.GetValue();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old one, but I was looking for the same information for a WPF application I'm working on. I found this site to be really helpful:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/206458-the-right-way-to-get-values-from-form1-to-form2/

This is written for Windows Forms, but if you ignore the part about passing values to the new window, it still worked and had some really good information.

On a side note, to pass values to the new window, this was really helpful:

[WPF passing string to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547904/wpf-passing-string-to-new-window)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While the links you provided may be helpful, it is always better to put main points to your post directly. This way, your answer doesn't become irrelevant if a link gets broken and also is easier to use and more helpful. So I recommend to edit your answer accordingly. Best regards