# How can I do that my userControl disappears when is validated?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm following some instructions from here:

[WPF Window Return Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468433/wpf-window-return-value)

I'm showing a user control in my window. The user control contains several controls, when is validated (I mean, the user has entered all the data) I need to show another user control.

I'm using a border like container.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here. Your question seems to suggest you have two user controls in one window, and you need to hide one when completed, and show another (like a wizard) but your link is about a dialog windows? Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve, maybe post a sample of what you've got?

Comment: Yeah your right, the window looks like a wizard. Although only get the trick in the link (create properties) but I'm not showing dialog windows

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do this.  I don't know that it's the best way, but then I also don't know if this way of designing a UI is all that good in the first place.  For instance, if my control vanishes when I put valid data into it, how do I get it back if I realize I made a mistake?  There's a reason wizards have a "Back" button.

First, create a base view model class that exposes a boolean `IsValid` property.  (In my example, I'm calling it `ValidatingViewModelBase`.)  Each of your views will use a view model derived from this class.  In each view model, once all of the properties are valid, set `IsValid` to true.

Next, create a user control for each view model as you'd do in any MVVM application.  The UI will make more sense if they are designed to be the same size.

Now, create a view model that exposes instances of these view models as properties (in my example, they're called `Page1`, `Page2`, etc.) and create a view that's bound to it:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="{x:Type ValidatingViewModelBase}"> 
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            </DataTrigger>
      </Style>
   <local:UserControl4 DataContext="{Binding Page4}"/>
   <local:UserControl3 DataContext="{Binding Page3}"/>
   <local:UserControl2 DataContext="{Binding Page2}"/>
   <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Page1}"/>
</Grid>
```

(This assumes that the `DataContext` for the grid is already set.)

How this works:  The `Grid` presents the controls in the same space on the screen, ordered from back to front.  Since they're the same size, and they're opaque, only the last one presented is visible.

When the `IsValid` property gets set on the `Page1` view, the style changes its `Visibility` to `Hidden`.  Now page 2 is visible.  This continues until all four pages are valid.  Since we're setting `Visibility` to `Hidden`, and not `Collapsed`, the `Grid` remains the same size even after all four pages are invisible.

I haven't tested this, so I don't know how bad a time you're going to have with focus issues.  When page 1 becomes invisible, you probably want the first control on page 2 to get the keyboard focus.  You may need to look at the discussion of logical focus in the [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) for ideas of how to deal with this.