# WPF passing string to new window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to pass a string to a new window when it is opened and it is not working.  Here is the code in Window 1;

**Window 1**

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newMyWindow2 = new myWindow2();
    newMyWindow2.Show();
    newMyWindow2.myString = "The great String Value";
}
```

In Windows 2 here is my declaration of the string;

**Windows 2**

```
public partial class myWindow2 : Window
{
    public string myString { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it the string is coming out NULL.  Why is this?

Comment: Where are you accessing the string from the second window?  Odds are it's before the first window has set the property, i.e. in the constructor or sometime before or right after the form is shown.

Comment: Why not pass the string through `myWindow2`'s constructor?

Comment: @HighCore agreed, great tutorials on msdn.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what I would do. Pass the string into the constructor, then assign it.

```
 public myWindow2(string value)
 {
     InitializeComponent();

     this.myString = value;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your showing the window before setting the string value which means the window is loading with a null value for `myString`.  Either pass the string value as a parameter to the constructor or define a default value like `string.Empty`.

Comment: Doing this
    var newMyWindow2 = new myWindow2();
    newMyWindow2.myString = string.Empty;
    newMyWindow2.myString = "The great String Value";
    newMyWindow2.Show();
Did not make a difference

Comment: @Xaphann You should start by [answering the questions asked of you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547904/wpf-passing-string-to-new-window#comment30727097_20547904) so that we can have enough information to answer the question, rather than trying to guess, as Lee is.