# Pass value from main window to child window and then return multiple values from child window to main window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main window and would like to pass a value to a Pop Up window (which will use that value to set up some other values dependant on that value). The pop up window has multiple textboxes for user inputs. When a button called SaveButton is pressed I would like the user inputs (all of them) to be sent back to the main window. How can I accomplish this?

I am very new to C# and I am aware that there are similar questions. However, I am having difficulties with adapting the answers to my specific situation. Thank you for keeping that in mind when answering!

Thank you so much!

---

Edit: About the code
The code that I have:
For initiating the PopUp window (which is a Window WPF called PopUp)

```
PopUp popUp = new PopUp();
popUp.ShowDialog
```

The PopUp.xaml.cs is empty except for the standard stuff and an eventhandler for the click event of the button.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community. You should provide us with some code that you are working with in order for us to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you show the popup window as dialog (blocking) or as an indepentent second window?

Comment: I will add some code to my question now!

Comment: If your PopUp class is inheriting System.Windows.Window then you should add a constructor for it and pass any information to the window by instantiaing it using that constructor. Simple example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547904/wpf-passing-string-to-new-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this :

Your main window :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //Defining public or internal parameters
    public int MainWindowProp1 { get; set; }
    public string MainWindowProp2 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When you call your child window, pass this (mainwindow) as parameter.
        childWindow cw = new WpfApplication1.childWindow(this);
        cw.Param2 = "test";
        cw.Param1 = 12;
        cw.Closed += Cw_Closed;
        cw.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Cw_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //On closed event, you can cast the sender as your child window.
        var child = (sender as childWindow);
        var param1 = child.Param1;
        var param3 = child.Param2;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //do anything you want
    }
}
}
```

And your Child Window :

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for childWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class childWindow : Window
{
    //declare Mainwindow as a parameter in your child window
    public MainWindow mainWindow;
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    //Add a parameter in your child window contructor.
    public childWindow(MainWindow _mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Assign your global parameter mainWindow to the _mainWindow parameter. 
        this.mainWindow = _mainWindow;
        this.Loaded += ChildWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void ChildWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //You can get or set your main window properties. 
        this.mainWindow.MainWindowProp1 = 5;
        this.mainWindow.MainWindowProp2 = "test";

        //You can call methods ant events etc.. of your main window too (depending on acces modifiers).
      this.mainWindow.TestMethod();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general terms the most simplified solution is this one:

From MainWindow to Child window (Window1);

```
((Window1)Application.Current.Windows[1]).testlabel.Content = "In Sync";
```

From child window to MainWindow;

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).label2.Content = "whatever";
```